# Need understanding of not in clause with this query

Tags: sql

I am new to the SQL, working on this query and found interesting output, please help in understanding why the output is different. Giving literal `manager_id` values in `NOT IN` clause (query 1) returns records, but if I use the subquery to return same literal values inside the `NOT IN` clause (query 2) 0 records are returned.
Thanks in advance

**Query 1:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM employees
WHERE employee_id NOT IN (
  100, 123, 120, 121, 147, 108, 148, 149, 205, 102, 201, 101, 114, 124, 145, 146, 103, 122
);
```

Result 1:

```
COUNT(*)
--------
89
```

**Query 2:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM employees
WHERE employee_id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT manager_id
  FROM employees
);
```

Result 2:

```
COUNT(*)
--------
0
```

Shouldn't it output the same result set?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help here

Comment: I think i found issue, the subquery returns null also along with above mentioned manager_id's

Answer (score 0):

If you query the same table in an subquery you need to give the tables an alias.
This is nessecary, otherwise the columns aren’t unique to identify.
It has nothing to do with the not.

Try this:

```
select count(e.*) 
from employees e 
where EMPLOYEE_ID not in
(select distinct m.manager_id from EMPLOYEES m where m.manager_id is not null);
```

Comment: in this case in `NOT IN()` it is not nessecary to use a alias or use fully qualified naming.. Only if use a corelated subquery `SELECT * FROM employees_outer ... NOT IN(SELECT ... WHERE employees_inner.id = employees_outer.id)` (as unrelated to question example)  then yes then it is nessecary..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I didn’t know this, but for readability, I always prefer aliasing.

Comment: *"but for readability"* agree i always use fully qualified naming meself just because the explain shows the alias not the table name when using aliases, makes it more easy to use explain on a query but matter of tasts

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with subquery returning the null value 
select DISTINCT(MANAGER_ID) from employees;
(null)
100
123
120
121
147
108
148
149
205
102
201
101
114
124
145
146
103
122